# Need explanation about javascript function and callback

Tags: javascript

im learning javascript, and i have been following some video tutorial on youtube

this is the original code

```js
function add(first, second, callback){
    console.log(first+second);
    callback();
}

function logDone(){
    console.log("done");
}

add(2,3,logDone);
```

and the result of code on above is

> 5
>   main.js (line 4)
>
> done
>   main.js (line 9)

and i make slight change to the code into this

```js
function add(first, second, callback){
    console.log(first+second);
    callback;
}

function logDone(){
    console.log("done");
}

add(2,3,logDone());
```

and the result is this

> done
>   main.js (line 9)
>
> 5
>   main.js (line 4)

my question are:

1. could you explain to me why i got the result pile up that way?,
2. and what the difference if we call a function with the bracket () and without the bracket ()?

Comment: Because without the brackets, you're not yet calling it - you just pass the function as an argument. It gets called in the `callback();` line.

Comment: As you called the function logDone by adding the brackets in the second code snippet you get the console log first

Comment: JavasScript evaluates arguments first. So if you have `foo(bar())`, `bar` is called first and its return value is passed to `foo`. Is btw is how most programming languages work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Explanation of the first snippet**

```
function add(first, second, callback) {
    console.log(first + second);
    callback(); // run whatever the "callback" function is
}

function logDone() {
    console.log("done");
}

add(2, 3, logDone); // pass in a function (not an invocation of a function) the
                    // function isn't run here
```

**Explanation of the second snippet**

```
function add(first, second, callback) {
    console.log(first + second);
    callback; // display the value of whatever "callback" is
}

function logDone() {
    console.log("done");
}

add(2, 3, logDone()); // run "logDone" and then pass the result (which in this
                      // case is undefined) into add
```

As you can see, the first code snippet doesn't actually run the `callback` until in the `add` function, whereas the second snippet runs the `callback` before `add` so that it can pass whatever comes back from `logDone` into `add`.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it becomes more clear to you when I alter the `logDone` declaration to this:

```
var logDone = function() {
    console.log("done");
}
```

The identifier `logDone` basically is just a variable that references a function. To execute (also: *call*, or: *invoke*) the function you add parentheses: `logDone()`.

So, in your first example you are merely passing the function *itself* as the third argument to `add()`, which then gets executed inside `add()`, with `callback();`.

In your second example, however, you are *executing* the function with `logDone()` immediately, which results in the return value of `logDone()`<sup>1</sup> being passed as the third argument to the `add()` call. In other words, first `logDone` is executed (resulting in the first log message), *then* `add` is executed (resulting in the second log message).

Furthermore, the statement `callback;`, inside `add`, does not do anything. And if you would have left the parentheses just like in your first example, it would result in an error, because `undefined`<sup>2</sup> is not a function.

---

1) which is `undefined` in this case, because `logDone()` does not explicitly return anything.

2) the value that was the result of the `logDone()` call.

Answer (score 3):

> and what the difference if we call a function with the bracket () and without the bracket ()?

If you have `()` then you call it. If you don't, then you don't.

> could you explain to me why i got the result pile up that way?,

In the first example you pass a function to `add` and then the `add` function calls it.

In the second example, you call the function and pass its return value (`undefined`) to `add` which then mentions it in a statement but doesn't do anything with it.

Answer (score 3):

When you do `func([args=optional])`, `func` is getting *invocated* or *called*.

> and what the difference if we call a function with the bracket () and
>   without the bracket ()?

We *call* the function only when we do `()`(arguments optional). When a function is without parenthesis, you're just using it's *reference*.

By storing a *reference* do a function in a variable, you can call it later, that's what `callback` is doing.

In the second snippet, since nothing is returned, callback will have `undefined`. Try calling it by doing `callback()` in the second snippet, and you should see an error stating,

> `undefined` is not a function.

Answer (score 3):

In the first example, you are passing a function as a parameter.
In your second example, you are passing a functions result after invocation as a parameter.